# try_files seemingly looking in wrong directory

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up try_files, but am running into an issue: It seems the fallback "empty.png" file is not picked up, even though it is located at `/path/to/old_cache_data/empty.png`. The files that actually exist (i.e. no fallback) are found without problems. Also interesting enough I am not getting an nginx 404, but the 404 page from the app that is handled by the proxy_pass below.

Stuff I tried so far:

- Removing the leading slash, which lead to this curious error: `open() "/usr//htmlempty.png" failed (2: No such file or directory)`, Seems weird to me as /usr/html is not specified anywhere as any sort of fallback path.
- Specifying an absolute path (i.e. `try_files $uri /path/to/old_cache_data/empty.png;`)

Relevant rules:

```
# legacy static cache
location /cache/ {
    root /path/to/old_cache_data;
    try_files $uri /empty.png;
}

# pass-through
location / {
    [bunch of proxy-settings]
    proxy_pass [the target url];
}
```

So, not sure where exactly I'm "holding it wrong". It seems like `try_files` does not pick up on the `root` in the location but somehow does a weird fallback.

**EDIT**: I found out that placing the empty.png in the "cache" sub-folder and changing the try_files to `try_files $uri /cache/empty.png;` actually works. I do not understand why this is the case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stated by the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), last parameter of the `try_files` directive can be

- a new URI;
- HTTP error code: `=code`;
- named location ID: `@location_name`.

You are using `/empty.png` which is treated as a new URI that **does not fall** under the `location /cache { ... }` thus being served by the `location / { ... }`. When you remove the leading slash you get the new URI `empty.png` that **does not fall under any of your locations including `location / { ... }`**. Every `server` block have some default root path `prefix/html` where prefix is specified at the [compilation time](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/installoptions/) and can be checked with the `nginx -V` command (looks like yours is `/usr/`). So as being said by the `root` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root),

> A path to the file is constructed by merely adding a URI to the value of the `root` directive.

which gives us prefix `/usr/` + default root `/html` + URI `empty.png` = `/usr//htmlempty.png`.

When you change last `try_files` parameter to the `/cache/empty.png`, this URI is served with the same `location /cache { ... }` block with the file `/path/to/old_cache_data` + `/cache/empty.png` = `/path/to/old_cache_data/cache/empty.png`. And if you understand all the above information correctly, you should notice that with your configuration you can't access any files in the `/path/to/old_cache_data` folder except those in the `/path/to/old_cache_data/cache` subfolder. Check the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directives for better understanding.

Comment: Aaaah that actually makes a lot of sense. Yeah I misunderstood it to simply be a file and didn't think about it as just another URL that gets re-evaluated. Thanks a lot :)